# What are "parameter expanded models"?

Tags: terminology, glmm

[Hadfield (2010)](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v33/i02/) talks about "parameter expanded models" (page 11). I never heard of these models before and wonder what he means by this. In the Appendix E he writes more about "Parameter expansion" and cites [Liu, Rubin and Wu (1998)](http://www.stat.ucla.edu/~ywu/research/papers/PXEM.pdf). As far as I grasped this paper they add parameters to their EM-algorithm models to speed up convergence.

My question is: **what are "parameter expanded models"** (in the context of generalized linear mixed models)**?**